# Reading wireless game controller

Tags: controller, serial-port, usb, processing, wireless

I have a Logitech Cordless RumblePad 2, connected via an USB wireless adapter. It's shown as `Logitech Cordless RumblePad 2` (HID or USB) under Device MAnager in `Human Interface Devices`.

I'd like to read it using Processing but I'm not sure how. If it was shown under `Ports (COM % LPT)` it would be easy to use the `Serial` class.

Windows says the location of the device is `Port_#0004.Hub_#0005`. How do I read this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device is a HID device, then the answer is that sadly, no you cannot manipulate the device via processing.

http://www.processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1159139976.html shows some discussion of the topic. I'm sure there's a work around, but there isn't default support.

On the other hand there is a author who gives a set-up for doing arbitrary USB devices http://tim.cexx.org/?p=470

I'm not sure how applicable to your situation.